# How can I remove a row in Google Sheets where the same data appears in another row?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with thousands of rows. The problem is some of the email addresses are listed twice, but the rows are not identical. I want to remove rows that have an email that already appears.

[image]

I want to remove the entire row 2, 4, 8 & 9 - because the email address has already been listed. How?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `UNIQUE` function. Check out the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en). You could make another sheet, use `UNIQUE` to get a list of all the unique emails, then use either `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX`&`MATCH` to get the corresponding name. If that example data of on Sheet 1 try Sheet 2 like this:

`Sheet2!B1 =UNIQUE(Sheet1!C:C)` to get a unique list of emails

`Sheet2!A1 =INDEX(Sheet1!B:B, MATCH(B1, Sheet1!B:B, 0))` Drag this down through the column to apply it to all the cells. It goes through that unique list, matches it to the an email in your original dataset, and shosw the corresponding client. It should take the first client it sees, so in the example you gave, 'quack@quack.com' will show 'duck' as the client.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give this a try looks like it'l work.